# How to pass the "lnkclass" value from partial view to stored procedure in mvc application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created parent and partial view. I am making an ajax call (using the `$.load()` function) to call my `RacesName()` method to get a value associated with the `data-raceid` attribute a my buttons. I then want to update the text generated by `@ViewBag.Name` with that value.

I getting following error

> GET `http://localhost:53987/Races/RacesName?id=103646584` 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Model

```
public class clsStakes
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int? RaceId { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Stakes(ClsStakes clsStakes)
{       
    return View(clsStakes);//return parent view
}   

public ActionResult RacesName(ClsStakes clsStakes, int? id)
{
    RacesDetails racesDetails = new RacesDetails();
    ViewBag.Name = racesDetails.RaceName(id);
     return View(clsStakes); // I think this part is creating problem.
}
```

Parent view

```
<div class="container">
     @ViewBag.Name            
     <div id="mypartial"></div>      
</div>
```

Partial View (this is rendered in the `<div id="mypartial">` element of the main view using a separate ajax call which is working)

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Date)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Race)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
            <td>
                <button class="linkClass" type="button" data-raceid="@item.RaceId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Race)</button>                   
            </td>                         
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Script to get raceid

```
$('#mypartial').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {
    var race = $(this).data("raceid");
    var raceid = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Stakes")?id=' + race;
    $(this).load(raceid);
});
```

Finally,Procedure to get the racename

```
public string RaceName(int? Id)
{
    SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
    string sSQL;
    var RaceName = "";
    sSQL = "exec StakesRacesGetRaceDetails @Id";
    prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
    prms[0].Value = Id;
    ds = clsUtilities.CreateCommandwithParams(sSQL, prms);
    DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];          
    if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[0];
        RaceName = Convert.ToString(row["race_header"]);
    }
    return RaceName;
}
```

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is in your C# logic on the server. I'd suggest you set a breakpoint and step through after making the AJAX call. A try/catch block would also be a good idea

Comment: You `RacesName()` method is nor making sense. First your using the `.load()` function which expects html (a `View`, not json). Second your setting the value of `ViewBag` but that just ignored when you return a `JsonResult`. It is not clear what your want to happen when you ajax call executes

Comment: Now you are returning a `View` - do you have a view named `RacesName.cshtml`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Actually, as there is not view for `public ActionResult RacesName(ClsStakes clsStakes, int? id)` so I am getting this error. But if i change the return type to `Json` then the whole partial values get replaced with this Json value. Please suggest me  how to return the single string which I can pass into parent view.

Comment: Is the single string you are referring to the value of `racesDetails.RaceName(id);`? And is so, what do you want to do with it (what part of the DOM do you want to update)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, No there is no view called `RacesName.cshtml`.Actually, I want to grab the racename from procedure and display into parent view. I tried in this way which is not giving me solution. Please guide me.

Comment: You need to answer my questions

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes I am referring to `racesDetails.RaceName(id);`. Actually, I want to display the racename as you can see in my parent view. So for that I have used ViewBag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170137/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user9895).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your controller method is throwing and exception. You can use you browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the result of you ajax call which will show the details of the exception. In this case, as identified in the comments, you do not have a view named `RacesName.cshtml`

One option is to create a partial view named (say) `_RacesName.cshtml` which contains only

```
@ViewBag.Name
```

and then the controller method will be

```
public ActionResult RacesName(int? id)
{
    RacesDetails racesDetails = new RacesDetails();
    ViewBag.Name = racesDetails.RaceName(id);
    return PartialView("_RacesName");
}
```

and modify the main view to

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="racename">@ViewBag.Name</div> // add container element        
     <div id="mypartial"> </div>      
</div>
```

and the script to

```
$('#mypartial').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {
    var race = $(this).data("raceid");
    var url = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Stakes")?id=' + race;
    $('#racename').load(url);
});
```

Alternatively, you can just return a `JsonResult` and update the DOM.
Modify the controller to

```
public ActionResult RacesName(int? id)
{
    RacesDetails racesDetails = new RacesDetails();
    string raceName = racesDetails.RaceName(id);
    return JsonResult(raceName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the script to

```
$('#mypartial').on('click', '.linkClass', function () {
    var race = $(this).data("raceid");
    var url = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Stakes")';
    $.getJSON(url, { id: race }, function(response) {
        $('#racename').text(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.This is simple and best solution of my problem.

Comment: As a side note, since you model already contains a property named `RaceName`, why not just add that value in you button as a `data-racename="@item.RaceName` attribute, and then use that rather than making an ajax call?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake `RaceName` is added in the model. I will remove it from there.